# How to deal with missing values in Fishnet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features, vector-grid

I m working with ArcMap 10.2.2.

I have one dataset with red deer observation (Excel Sheet)
The data is joined to a polygon layer with administrative boudaries:
It looks like this

[image: Red deer observation data]

Blue are the red deer observations counted with zero (means data is available and zero animals are counted)
Yellow are areas where data didn't exist therefore I assigned the value -9999

I intersect my red deer data with a fishnet grid with cellsize 1000 -
No problem but when updating the fishnet - I summarize the red deer data by calculating the average.

I m getting wrong values in exactly this grid cells

[image: Fisnet grid cell intersect and outcome updated values]

Does anybody know how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Use select by attributes to exclude no data polygons